# Restoring submit button after php script finishes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using Ajax with PHP to post data to PHP and get the output to my current page without loading it, I'm sending the data using Submit button, and when this button is clicked I replaced this button with loading.gif. Now after the php script finishes and I get the output, the loading.gif keep showing. My question is how do I restore the submit button after the PHP script is finished and I want to submit more data without refreshing the page?

Edit:
Form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQuery Form Example</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform").validate({

            submitHandler: function(form) {
                // do other stuff for a valid form
                $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ButtonClicked(){

    document.getElementById("formsubmitbutton").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
     document.getElementById("buttonreplacement").style.display = ""; // to display
    return true;
    }


    </script>


</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">  
<!-- The Name form field -->
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>
<!-- The Email form field -->
    <label for="email" id="email_label">Email</label>  
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value=""/> 
    <br>
<!-- The Submit button -->
                <div align="center" style="margin-bottom:-100px;" id="formsubmitbutton"><input  type="submit" value="Submit"  onclick="ButtonClicked()" /></div>
        <center><div   id="buttonreplacement" style="display:none;">
        <img src="http://redscopestudios.com/wp-content/uploads/edge_suite/project/red-scope_6/images/red_loader.gif"alt="loading..."></div></center>
</form>
<!-- We will output the results from process.php here -->
<div id="results"><div>
</body>
</html>
```

process.php

```
<?php
    print "Form submitted successfully: <br>Your name is <b>".$_POST['name']."</b> and your email is <b>".$_POST['email']."</b><br>";
?>
```

Comment: Show us your code, please !

Comment: Don't replace the button, hide it instead and then just show it again once the PHP script has finished.

Comment: Do exactly the same to change it but in the different direction in your success function

Comment: @zlen I'm not looking for a code, just want some suggestion on how to do it.

Comment: Need your code to modify it !

Comment: @michael I used onclick to call a function to show loading.gif, now I don't know how to specify that the php script finished.

Comment: post your code and we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand what you want correctly you can do the following:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    // do other stuff for a valid form
    $("#formsubmitbutton").hide();
    $("#buttonreplacement").show();

    $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
        $("#formsubmitbutton").show();
        $("#buttonreplacement").hide();
    });
}
```

Then remove your ButtonClicked method, it's not needed if you are already hooking into the form submit event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').fadeOut();
```

Then after the ajax has finished (in the call back)

```
$('button').fadeIn();
```

This would fade our the button and then fade it back in. Replacing the button isn't necessary, and shouldn't be done.